# print 1 to 100 in php using recursive function without parameter and condition

Tags: php

Below is the code, can it be done without any condition? In this case remove if condition.

```
function printme(){
    static $min=1;
    $max = 100;
    echo $min.' ';
    if($min < $max ){
        $min++;
        printme();
    }
}
printme();
```

output :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Comment: No, because somewhere you will have to check if you've reached $max. Btw this is probably the most useless function I have ever seen.

Comment: Yhea so my question is can a recursive function do the job without a condition?

Comment: Not sure what the goal of your function is but this would get the job done `echo implode(' ', range(1, 100));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *pragmatic* answer, at least, is "no." A recursive function *must* have an exit condition which causes the recursion to stop. It must test for that condition.

Anything that tries not to do that is "code golf," including Rax's answer above which merely *conceals* the existence of the necessary conditional tests. (In that case, it's buried in `str_repeat()`, which contains a loop that stops after 100 iterations.)

Comment: Suit yourself. It's the only answer that there is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<?php
function printme(){     
    preg_replace_callback('/ /', function() {
        static $i;
        print ++$i."\n";
    }, str_repeat(' ', 100));
}
printme();
?>
```

Comment: it's good, but i need recursive i.e. printme should get call atleast once.

Answer (score 0):

You said no `if()` so how about a `while()`?

```
function printme(){
    static $min=1;
    $max = 100;
    echo $min.' ';
    while($min < $max ){
        $min++;
        printme();
    }
}
printme();
```

---

No conditional statement

```
error_reporting(0);

function printme(){
    static $min = 0;
    ++$min;

    $func = "print$min";
    $func();

    printme();
}

function print1(){echo '1 ';};
function print2(){echo '2 ';};
// 3 - 99
function print100(){echo '100';};

printme();
```